# Crawler does not correctly select the nodes of a XML on Symfony 2.3

Tags: xml, symfony, xpath, symfony-2.3, web-crawler

I am doing an application to import QTI and I has come the following problem:

I get an XML file containing the test (assessmentTest), which in turn contain references to the questions (named as assessmentItems). The XML file is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<assessmentTest xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsqti_v2p1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsqti_v2p1 imsqti_v2p1.xsd" identifier="AT-196b0997-3ec6-4b4e-8b22-c3d563f71291" title="Quiz example">
  <outcomeDeclaration identifier="SCORE" cardinality="single" baseType="float" />
  <testPart identifier="TP-9ee1d731-c360-4989-bb50-c8bae65d2f8a-2" navigationMode="nonlinear" submissionMode="simultaneous">
    <assessmentSection identifier="AS-b602c887-a711-417b-bfad-6fe005fc085f-3" required="false" fixed="false" title="" visible="true" keepTogether="true">
      <selection select="2" withReplacement="false" />
      <ordering shuffle="true" />
      <assessmentItemRef identifier="AIR-5d0d9526-80ba-4956-8017-0fe6b9ef45d7-9" href="test/AI-15149c8b-8856-4117-9de3-e073552e668d-4.xml" />
      <assessmentItemRef identifier="AIR-c112b4d4-6003-4d17-a2c5-55a2d3d6388c-24" href="test/AI-b6b27861-3d27-4876-afb3-c33daf2d7fad-19.xml" />
    </assessmentSection>
  </testPart>
  <outcomeProcessing>
    <setOutcomeValue identifier="SCORE">
      <sum>
        <testVariables variableIdentifier="SCORE" />
      </sum>
    </setOutcomeValue>
  </outcomeProcessing>
  <testFeedback access="atEnd" showHide="hide" outcomeIdentifier="outcomeIdentifier" identifier="outcomeValue" title="Detailed Breakdown">
    <p>The test is now complete. The following table shows a breakdown of your scores:</p>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>The total score:</td>
          <td>
            <printedVariable identifier="SCORE" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </testFeedback>
</assessmentTest>
```

I use the following code to get the references:

```
 if (!empty($assessmentsTest)) {
     foreach ($assessmentsTest as $assessmentTest) {
         $crawler = new Crawler (file_get_contents(sys_get_temp_dir()."/qti-pack/".$assessmentTest));

         $items = $crawler->filterXPath('/assessmentTest/testPart/assessmentSection//assessmentItemRef');

         for ($i=0; $i < $items->count(); $i++) { 
             $assessmentsItem [] = $items->eq($i)->attr('href');
         }
     }
 }
```

But this doesnt work well. if I ignore the 'for' and use a more direct code:

```
echo $items->eq(0)->attr('href');
```

Returm me the following error: "The current node list is empty."

I've tried other variations of the xPath but get the same error.

P.D.: Sorry for my bad english, it's not my native language.

Answer (score 2):

I do not using Symfony but this is a common problem in handling XML. Your XML has default namespace (`xmlns="..."`) defined at the root level, so all nodes without different default namespace declaration and without prefix are considered in the aforementioned default namespace.

According to [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html), starting from version 2.4 default namespace registered automatically with `default` prefix, so you can try using this XPath :

```
/default:assessmentTest/default:testPart/default:assessmentSection/default:assessmentItemRef
```

**UPDATE :**

It is a bit hard for me to find documentation on internet regarding manual namespace prefix registration in Symfony2, could you try something like this (got the idea from [here](http://gitelephant.cypresslab.net/symfony-2/commit/9110468e9982f825cd5a3941f31f6028effcd5ec)) :

```
$crawler->registerNamespace('default', 'http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsqti_v2p1')
$items = $crawler->filterXPath('/default:assessmentTest/default:testPart/default:assessmentSection/default:assessmentItemRef');
```

Comment: Sorry, Im using Symfiny 2.3 and 'default:assessmentTest/default:testPart/default:assessmentSection/default:assessmentItemRef' dont work for me, Im try this. I've edited the title to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

I answer to myself:

```
if (!empty($assessmentsTest)) {
    foreach ($assessmentsTest as $assessmentTest) {
        $crawler = new Crawler();
        $crawler->addXmlContent(file_get_contents(sys_get_temp_dir()."/qti-pack/".$assessmentTest));

        $items = $crawler->filterXPath('//assessmentItemRef');

        for ($i=0; $i < $items->count(); $i++) { 
            $assessmentsItem [] = $items->eq($i)->attr('href');
        }
    }
}
```

The end is a simple solution.